# datas are in array format ;Remove lines from file1 that exist in file2 in Powershell

Tags: powershell

FILE1

```
Data   status   error

0001   running    0

0002   process    1

0003   end        2
```

FILE2

```
Data   status   error

0001   process   1

0002   running   2

0004   end       3
```

Based on comparing data on file 1 and file 2 (BASED ON DATA Column), remove the duplicates in file 1.

Output:in file 1:

should be all deleted.

```
Data    Status   error

0003    end       2
```

```
$first_file = type .\old.txt | % {​​​ $_.Split(" ") | select -first 1 }​​​
$second_file = type .\new.txt | % {​​​ $_.Split(" ") | select -first 1 }​​​

$f_s = $first_file | ?{​​​-not ($second_file -contains $_)}​​​
$s_f = $second_file | ?{​​​-not ($first_file -contains $_)}​​​
```

I tried this way as I am new on powershell.  Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Are the files really like that, or is this just a formatted view of the data. It _looks_ like they could be CSV files.. Can you open the files in notepad and show us **exactly** how they are structured in there?

Comment: yes ,i looks like sames as format but in notepad